# Run ADF pipeline without assigning 'Contributor' role at subscription level

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rbac

Appreciate for your advice if there is other approach i could try out..

I would like to run the ADF pipeline via RestFul API / .Net SDK and I have followed through the Microsoft tutorial for this.

[Microsoft Run ADF Pipeline link via Restful / SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api#authenticate-with-azure-ad)

Understand that Contributor role has to be assigned to the application (Subscription level).
However, assignment of contributor at subscription level is not allowed at my Client environment due to the security policy. Contributor role entitlement only allowed at resource group level.

Hence, may i have your advice if there is any other approach i could run ADF pipeline without assignment of contributor role at subscription level?

Below is the error message i gotten from my c# program:

```
System.AggregateException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=One or more errors occurred.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean 
includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean 
waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at ADFv2QuickStart.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
C:\Users\ADFv2QuickStart\Program.cs:line 59
Inner Exception 1:
CloudException: The client 'xxxxxx' with 
object id 'xxxxxx' does not have authorization 
to perform action 
'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/createRun/action' over scope 
'/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-xxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/adf-xxxx/pipelines/pipeline12'.
```

Comment: Does my solution work or not, could you let me know? Why keep silent?

Comment: My ID has been assigned to contributor role at resource group level.

I have inherited contributor role for Data Factory.

However, understand that contributor role has to be assigned to the application in Azure Active Directory. But this is not allowed at my client policy. May i have more advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Contributor role at the resource group level is enough, I start a run of a pipeline via powershell, it works fine. The command essentially calls the REST API : [Pipelines - Create Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun), so you will also be able to invoke the REST API directly.

```
Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -DataFactoryName joyfactoryv2 -PipelineName pipeline1
Get-AzDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -DataFactoryName joyfactoryv2 -PipelineRunId "xxxxxxx"
```

[image]

In the screenshot, you will find if I get the web app in another resource group, it will give the error, so we can make sure the role is working. `Invoke-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline` will return the `RunId`, just pass it in the `Get-AzDataFactoryV2PipelineRun`, you can get the details of the PipelineRun.

Catch the request, we could find what I mentioned above, it calls the REST API. It is the same with the one in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api#create-pipeline-run) in your question.

[image]

Comment: Hi Joy, appreciate for your quick respond.

My ID (user) has been assigned to contributor role at resource group level.

I have inherited contributor role for Data Factory.

However, understand that contributor role has to be assigned to the application in Azure Active Directory. But this is not allowed at my client policy. May i have more advice on this?

Comment: @ChooiLingSiToh No, you do not need to go to Azure Active Directory. Just use an owner(contributor role can not assign role to others) account of your subscription, go to the resource group ->  `Access control (IAM)`, assign the role to application like the same way of assigning to user, see :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal

Comment: @ChooiLingSiToh If you do not have the owner account of the subscription, you may need to ask your client to help you to assign the role for your application.

Comment: @ChooiLingSiToh If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer, thanks.

Comment: let me have a words with my client IT personal to assign the contributor role to the Application (which is created in ADD) at Resource Group. i do not have owner role. It might take some days due to the organization processes..... Definitely I will mark the answer once it works :) again, thank u very much for your prompt respond.. very much appreciated. I hope it will works.

Comment: @ChooiLingSiToh If your application has the contributor role, I am 100% sure it can create a run of a pipeline(in the permission tier, if some errors about the code, I am not sure).

Comment: no update yet. but i will make it as answers coz it seems promising. Will update again when there is feedback from my client IT